# jest ReferenceError: Vue is not defined

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, jestjs, vue-cli, vue-jest

We are introducing Jest to an existing project.

However, I wrote an example test code.
The above error occurred.

```
   ReferenceError: Vue is not defined

      1 | import User from "../components/modal/ad/AdAdd";
    > 2 | import { mount } from "@vue/test-utils";
        | ^
      3 |
      4 | describe("user component", () => {
      5 |   let wrapper;
```

How can I solve this??

```js
//User.test.js

import User from "../components/modal/ad/AdAdd";
import { mount } from "@vue/test-utils";

describe("user component", () => {
  let wrapper;
  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = mount(User);
  });
  test("render", () => {
    expect(wrapper.vm.oSid).toBe(0);
  });
});
```

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      Sid: 0,
      deleteList: [],
    };
  },
```

```js
//package.json
"dependencies": {
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^26.2.2",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vuetify": "^2.4.0",
    "vuex": "^3.4.0",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.18.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.18.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.1",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.0.5",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^6.0.0",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "^28.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "jest": "^28.1.0",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^28.1.0",
    "speed-measure-webpack-plugin": "^1.5.0",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^2.2.0",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "~2.4.0",
    "vue-jest": "^3.0.7",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11",
    "vuetify-loader": "^1.7.0"
  }
```

I just mounted it, but it says the view is undefined. I don't know how to solve it.

What's wrong??

I haven't been able to solve the above error for several days.

I want to solve it.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 25):

I had the same error with vue3 and jest v.28, what solved it was to add

```
    testEnvironmentOptions: {
       customExportConditions: ["node", "node-addons"],
    },
```

into `jest.config.js`. This overrides versions of the library loaded from `exports` in `package.json` as explained [in jest config page](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#testenvironmentoptions-object). As it defaults to `['browser']` for `jest-environment-jsdom`, and my failing tests were all that targeted the UI, presumably the right libraries were not imported for the `jsdom` environment.

Alternatively, if you want a solution that doesn't affect other imports, add this to `jest.config.js` instead:

```
moduleNameMapper: {
  "^@vue/test-utils": "<rootDir>/node_modules/@vue/test-utils/dist/vue-test-utils.cjs.js"
}
```

This will tell Jest to import the `'node'` version of `@vue/test-utils` without impacting other imports.

Comment: Could you elaborate ? I'm having the same issue but your solution doens't works for me

Comment: Don't know what it does, but now it works.

Comment: This only worked for me when I moved it to the top of the jest.config.js module.exports.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Vue version 2 with [@vue/test-utils 2.0.0](https://github.com/vuejs/test-utils) which is for Vue version 3.

You can find the correct @vue/test-utils version for Vue 2 [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-test-utils)

Comment: Also happens with Vue3